# Skip to not change input attribute element

Tags: jquery

i'm using this code to change all element attributes, 
how to skip in this code for not change any elemnt: for example,

```
$('[id^="lbl"] ! lbl1 ! lbl2').attr("disabled", true);
```

in that code lbl1 and lbl2 must be not change

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
$('[id^="lbl"]').not('#lbl1, #lbl2').prop("disabled", true);
```

Please note that you should, with attribute-equals/attribute-starts-with selectors, supply an identifying element-type (if possible), to reduce the amount of work jQuery has to do to find the given elements.

You could also use `filter()`:

```
$('[id^="lbl"]').filter(
    function(){
        var id = this.id;
        return id !== 'lbl1' && id !== 'lbl2';
    }).prop('disabled',true);
```

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: I think it should be `.not('#lbl1, #lbl2')`

Answer (score 1):

Try using not selector,

```
$('[id^="lbl"]').not('#lbl1, #lbl2').prop("disabled", true);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vQFdM/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[id^="lbl"]:not("#lbl1, #lbl2")').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Using `.prop` is more appropriate instead of `.attr`

Comment: @Vega just in case you are using modern jquery versions, then attr is ok too

Comment: @OscarJara I am not sure.. I use `.prop` anywhere it is boolean and `.attr` for string